# C++ custom assignment

Tags: c++

I have the following code:

```c
template<size_t rows, size_t cols>
class Matrix{
    std::array<int, rows * cols>  data;
public:
    int  operator()(size_t i, size_t j){
        return data[i * cols + j];
    }
//  ...code...
}
```

What is the best way to achieve this:

```c
Matrix<1,1> a;
a(0, 0) = 0;
```

avoiding the `lvalue required as left operand of assignment` error?

Comment: Change `int  operator()` to `int&  operator()`

Comment: You'll also need a second `const` overload of `operator()`.

Comment: What is that line of code supposed to do exactly?  Oh right, you have edited your question.  But why not `std::array<std::array<int, cols>, rows> data`?  I mean, if you _want_ a 2D array, then why don't you make yourself one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change the following line:

```
int  operator()(size_t i, size_t j){
```

To:

```
int & operator()(size_t i, size_t j){
```

Returning a refernce (L value reference to be precise) to the element in the Matrix will allow you to assign to it.

**Update:** Some notes to complete my answer:

1. As @user4581301 commented: you can see more info about C++ value categories here: [What are rvalues, lvalues, xvalues, glvalues, and prvalues?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3601602/what-are-rvalues-lvalues-xvalues-glvalues-and-prvalues)
2. As @Darth-CodeX and @HolyBlackCat mentioned, it is advisable to add a `const` overload for `operator()`:

```
int const & operator()(int i, int j) const { /* same implementation */ }
```

You can use it with a const `Matrix` for reading elements values: if you have e.g. a `Matrix const & m`, you can use `int val = m(0,0)` to read an element value (of cource you will not be able to use it for assignment due to constness).

Comment: Terminology helper: [What are rvalues, lvalues, xvalues, glvalues, and prvalues?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3601602/what-are-rvalues-lvalues-xvalues-glvalues-and-prvalues)

Answer (score 3):

You need to return the reference of the element from `data` like this:

```cpp
// can change
int &operator()(size_t i, size_t j)
{
    return data[i * cols + j];
}
```

And every STL container includes a `const` function, for the cases like `const Matrix &`

```cpp
// cannot change 
int operator()(size_t i, size_t j) const
{
    return data[i * cols + j];
}
```